# Codeigniter Ajax request to controller | Security Issues?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

A few months ago I stumbled across [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-codeigniter/) that was drafted about using jquery ajax calls to a controller, and have since then been using this method to code cases that would have otherwise been rather convoluted.

Upon further research I am finding multiple cases where people are saying that accessing the controller via the view this way is "unconventional" and that it breaks MVC pattern. Is this true? Would it be advised not to follow this method for ajax calls?

If this method is feasible(which at this point I'm hoping that it is because I have structured a large part of my current application around it) what would one have to do to secure the application? I noticed in the comments to the article that someone had mentioned to "leverage the $_SERVER variable"?

More or less looking for some advice about handling this scenario. Any information be it fact or opinion is greatly appreciated!

An example of the scenario from the article would be the following call to controller (I left out the model since I did not find it relevant to the post):

**VIEW CODE**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#rfUsername").focusout(function() {
        $username = $("#rfUsername").val();
        if($username != ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json",
                url: BaseURL + "profile/checkUsername",
                data: "username=" + $username,
                success: function(data){
                    usernameValid(data.isGood, data.message);
                }
            });
        } else {
            clearUsernameValidStatus();
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
```

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
function checkUsername(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $this->load->model('user_model');

    if($this->user_model->checkUsernameValidFormat($username) === false){
        $isGood = false;
        $message = 'Username must be at least 5 characters';
    } else {
        if($this->user_model->checkUsernameExists($username)){
            $isGood = false;
            $message = 'Sorry, that username is already taken';
        } else {
            $isGood = true;
            $message = 'Username is acceptable';
        }
    }

    echo json_encode(array('isGood' => $isGood, 'message' => $message));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woke up this morning and thought to myself, "Hey, why don't you just use session variables to determine if the user is actually on the server before executing the code in the controller?" I believe this will solve my delima. Will post back if I find an issue with this solution.

Comment: OP will surely deliver.

Comment: he didn't its been 3 years